# How to Make my unfilled int array not print out 0?

Tags: java

```
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    arr[0] = 23;
    arr[1] = 123;
    arr[2] = 255;

    printArray(arr);
}

static void printArray(int...arr) {
    for (int T : arr)
        System.out.println(T);
}
```

Prints this:

```
23
123
255
0
0
```

So how to avoid not printing unfilled elements, please?

Comment: Those positions are not unfilled - they contain `0`.

Comment: `int[] arr = new int[3];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitives in Java are not nullable. When you create a primitive integer and don't assign a value to it, [it will default to `0`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

You *can* make an array of `Integer`s which *are* nullable and then use an if to see if they are null like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];
     arr[0] = 23;
     arr[1] = 123;
     arr[2] = 255;

     printArray(arr);
}

public static void printArray(Integer... arr){
    for(Integer t : arr) {
        if (t != null) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using `Integer` instead of `int` is a huge performance drawback. However there is no other way to tell whether a value was set. Except one can choose a special value which can not occur in the application. For example a `-1` or so. Then one can initialize the array with `-1` instead of `0` like `Arrays.fill(array, -1);` and stick with `int`.

Comment: @Zabuza Good to point out, but I wonder on what scale it would become noticeable. And if the operation of `Arrays.fill()` would discard the overhead of using a boxed primitive.

Comment: Yeah. It would probably be better to use `0` as the *magic value* for the `int[]` and if a `0` is valid in the application, then put it as `-1` (the *magic value* which can not occur) in the array. By that you can use the default initialization with `0` efficiently though using another *indicator value*. Needs a method-wrapper for `get` and `set` access but for big data this might become favorable.